# I need my equations to overwrite data in a file every 10 iterations of a loop

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

```
double rho[1001], rhonew[1001];

int main(void)
{
    int tstep, tmax, n, nmax, r;
    double t, dt, x, dx;
    dt = 0.001;
    tmax = 1000;
    dx = 0.1;
    nmax = 1000;
    rho0=1.0;
    r=1;

    FILE *afinal;
    afinal = fopen("afinal.txt","w");
    FILE *amid;
    amid = fopen("amid.txt","w");

    for (n = 0; n <= nmax; n++)
    {
        rho[n] = 500;
    }        

    for (n = 0; n <= nmax; n++)
    {
        rhonew[n] = 1;
    }
    for (tstep=1; tstep<=tmax; tstep++)
    {
        rho[tstep] += -tstep;
        if(tstep == r*10)
//I want this if statement to execute every 10 "tsteps" to overwrite the data in amid.txt
        {
            for (n = 0; n <= nmax; n++)
            {
                x = n*dx;
                fprintf(amid, "%f \t %f \n", x, rho[n]);
            }
        fclose(amid);   
        r++;        
        }
    }

    for (n = 0; n <= nmax; n++)
    {
        x = n*dx;
        fprintf(afinal, "%f \t %f \n", x, rho[n]);
    }
    fclose(afinal);   
return 0;
}
```

My array "amid" only writes once, but I want it to write information, then overwrite that old information with new information several times within the greater "tmax" loop.  With this, I want to graph snapshots of my data through gnuplot "over time" so I can watch my differential equations' work evolve.

Answer (score 1):

do you mean like this?:

```
for (tstep=1; tstep<=tmax; tstep++)
{
    rho[tstep] += -tstep;
    if(tstep == r)
    {
        rewind(amid);
        for (n = 0; n <= nmax; n++)
        {
            x = n*dx;
            fprintf(amid, "%f \t %f \n", x, rho[n]);
        }
        r += 10;
    }
}

// later....
close(amid);
```

By the way: why do you use `rho[tstep] += -tstep;` instead of `rho[tstep] -= tstep;` ... this seems a bit hard to read, at least I had to read it twice, what you're doing there.

Maybe your problem is, that you close that file too early .. also watch your misleading indentation of your code.

Furthermore, you're supposed to *ask a question* here. What is your question actually?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
   if (tstep%10 == 0)
   //I want this if statement to execute every 10 "tsteps" to
   // overwrite the data in amid.txt
```

This is the mod operator.  It divides tstep by 10 and returns the remainder.  If the remainder is zero it then executes your for loop.

Also, if a "phase" is needed in your ten steps, then `tstep%10 == 2` or 1, 3, up to 9 then you would still exec the loop once every ten steps only with an offset with respect to the outer loop.

Comment: modulo (%) is a [heavy operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Performance_issues). Comparison to a fixed value and then adding 10 to that value each time is more efficient IMHO.

Comment: I doubt if you could benchmark the difference to any significant degree.  The real consideration is how difficult is it for someone else to read and maintain your code.  Programmers' time is much more valuable than milliseconds of a cpu.

Comment: The call to `fprintf()` has to be 100x, if not 1000x, many times more CPU usage than a `%` operator.  Absolutely agree: use `%`.

Comment: I agree with both of you.